# Rails 3 scope for next upcoming 'event'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, rails-activerecord

Trying to develop a scope for `:next` that will return the next, upcoming, 'event' (or whatever) given the model has `end_at`:

This will bring all the upcoming events:

```
scope :upcoming, lambda { where("end_at >= ?", Date.today).order("start_at") }
```

So figured that the following would return the first event from that ordered list:

```
scope :next,     lambda { where("end_at >= ?", Date.today).order("start_at").first }
```

but instead it returns ALL the events!?! identical to `Event.all`.

Anyway, what's the right way to build this scope?

Comment: Does your first scope (:upcoming) function correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `upcoming` scope is actually working, you can just call this from the `next` scope:

```
scope :next, lambda { upcoming.first }
```

I'm not sure this actually works, but I would recommend changing it to a class method:

```
def self.next
  upcoming.first
end
```

Comment: do you need lambda on the scope?

Comment: `scope :next, lambda { upcoming.first }` works! @Swards: i'd be interested to  know if there's an alternative w/out the lambda.

Comment: The lambda won't be required until Rails 4 comes out, but I've been using them so it's one less thing to have to deal with later. I also use the 1.9 lambda syntax so it's a little shorter: `scope :next, ->{ upcoming.first }`

Comment: Since you have lambda in the upcoming scope, I don't think you need it in next.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a class method and use that instead..

```
def self.next
    where("end at >= ?", Date.today).order("start_at").first
end
```